# Updating an Oracle table with respect to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

Lets say:

```
Table T1 with columns id,ref,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
Table T2 with columns id,ref,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
```

I need to update few columns in `T2(a2,c2,e2)` with respect to values in `T1(a1,c1,e1)` where `T1.ref = T2.ref`, given that `ref=<certain value>`.

For a particular value of ref column there are many records in each table.

I want to update **T2** with respect to **T1** for one particular value of ref column. Other records will be untouched.

I am currently doing this by dropping all the rows of `T2` and inserting the current rows from `T1` where `ref=<some value>`.

For ex: if the **ref value=5**

then I do these steps.

```
1. delete from T2 where ref=5;
2. insert into T2 (a2,c2,e2) select a1,c1,e1 from T1 where T1.ref = 5;
```

Certainly this is not a good method to synchronize the data between the two table.

Please suggest me an efficient solution to achieve this in Oracle.

I think i missed an important point. Both the tables have one column which clearly identifies each record. So I dont want the records to be in T2 which are not present in T1.
Just to reiterate -  for a value of column "ref" both the tables returns multiple records, and each record has an unique identifying column. Those records identified in T1 only needs to be present in T2.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Show your code which you have tried.

Comment: @ProgrammerIT The two steps mentioned is exactly my code i have tried, except for the table names and column names. I just want a more efficient way than this. These queries are doing the required work , I just want to do the same work with a more efficient way. Instead of deleting and adding all the records for a particular value of the column("ref"), i just want to update the required records alone. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have exact matching between each row of T1 and T2 then your method is good enough.

But if you have some kind of matching try to implement your logic with merge:

```
MERGE INTO t2 b
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM t1
  WHERE t1.ref = <value>) t1
ON (t2.<key> = t1.<key>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET <t2.values> = <t1.values>  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (<t2columns>)
  VALUES (<t1values>);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if there are records in T2 that are no longer required, I want those to be deleted. only the current rows in T1 needs to be preserved. older ones(now not present in T1) should be gone. I can see modifed rows are updated, and new rows are added by your query. but will the old ones be deleted. I am new to SQL. Kindly bear with my points if they are silly.

Comment: @Mohamed You can always run `DELETE` after `MERGE` or `UPDATE`, thus deleting the records you don't need. It's safe and is done within the same transaction.

Comment: This answer does the job well, but the performance was less than my previous process of deleting all the records and inserting all of them. Anyhow was able to learn this method. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like:

```
update t2 
  set (a2,c2,e2) = (select a1,c1,e1 from t1 where t1.ref = 5)
  where t2.ref = 5;
```

But you would have to make sure the nested query produces only one row.

Comment: the query `select a1,c1,e1 from t1 where t1.ref = 5` returns multiple records. What to do if the T2 has 10records for this ref value, and T1 has additional records, say T1 has 15records for the same ref value. I need additional records to be inserted and unwanted records to be deleted.

Comment: Do you have some rows in `T1` which are not yet inserted in `T2`? It wasn't clear whether you needed to update the rows in `T2`, or insert the new ones.

Comment: yes. exactly. T1 is the table which keeps on changing. for a particular value (ref), some rows may be deleted, news rows may be added or data may change in the existing rows. On user action am going to put the data into T2 from T1. This data synchronisation may include - rows deletion, rows updation and insertion of new rows. The ref value is going to come from user. kindly help me.

Comment: Then you could use the solution suggested by @Girafik, and `DELETE` to remove unneeded records. The actual `MERGE` statement could be slightly different though.